# Saving custom datatypes in Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this class structure that I need to store in Firebase Firestore.

```java
class A {
 int i = 3;
}
class B {
 A xa = new A();
 A ya = new A();
}
class C {
 B b = new B();
 String name = "hi";
}

C c1 = new C();
```

I want to store the value `c1` in a document.
 
One way of doing so is like this.

```js
db.collection("Cs").document("c1").set({
  "b": {
    "xa": {
      "i": 3,
    },
    "ya": {
      "i": 3,
    },
  },
  "name": "hi",
});
```

And another way of doing it.

```js
ref1 = db.collection("Cs").document("c1");
ref1.set({"name": "hi"});
ref2 = ref1.collection("B").document("b").collection("A");
ref2.document("xa").set({"i": 3});
ref2.document("xb").set({"i": 3});
```

Can anyone tell me what is the best way of doing this. If there is any other better way of doing this, can you please state that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a huge difference between those two approaches. In the first one you add those objects beneath a single document while in the second you are using nested collections.

> Can anyone tell me what is the best way of doing this.

Either the first approach nor the second is better to be used. I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but in general you should design the database schema for the queries you want to perform.

Comment: I have a class structure like above. I need a way to add it to the database. I might need to query data by `i` (Variable in `class A`).

Comment: To add to the database, simply add those objects using `set()` method. If you need to query by `i`, you can use `db.collection("Cs").whereEqualTo("b.va.i", 3);`.  I recommend you also take a look at [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), might help achieve easier the first solution.

Comment: With the help of [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), I can query data from 2nd method also. But what I need to know is, what is better in terms of standards. (Software architectural aspects.)

Comment: Knowing the in Firestore everything is about the number of reads and writes, first solution makes more sense since everything exists under a single document. The second solution implies writing to several collections, which in term means more read operations. So the first solution in my opinion is the one to go ahead with.